# How to concatenate several text files with a blank line in-between each?

Tags: scripting

I am writing a shell script, and in that I am using three html files. Now I am trying to concatenate all three files, and send the content as an email to my self.

Please see below what I am trying to do
three file: `hello.html`, `hello1.html` , `hello2.html`.

Now I am appending the output of all these three files to file `Final.Html` file like below and sending it, as an email.

```
>Final.html
cat hello.html >> Final.html
cat hello1.html >> Final.html
cat hello2.html >> Final.html
cat Final.html | sendmail -t
```

Now my input of all three files is shown below

```
$ cat hello.html
Hello world
$ cat hello1.html
india is my world
$ cat hello2.html
India is the best
```

After sending the mail, the output I am getting is below

```
Hello world
india is my world
India is the best
```

The output I am looking for is below with one empty line between each file. To get a clean and clear output.

```
Hello world

india is my world

India is the best
```

Comment: I think Brian may have been referring to the term “o/p” as an abbreviation for “output”.  I agree that “output” is more quickly understood. If these are really HTML files, do you need a `<br>` or similar HTML code, versus a blank line?

Answer (score 3):

This should give the required output,

```
awk 'NR>1 && FNR==1{print ""};1' ./*.html > /path/to/Final.html
```

(make sure the output file is not in the list of input files)

Comment: This is a neat solution, but it would be an even better answer if it had some description of what it is actually doing.

Comment: It will merge the contents of all files ending with .html by adding a new line after the contents of each file to Final.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do that all with one use of `cat` which, while it is often used to display the contents of *a* file on the terminal, is actually made for con- *cat* -enating files (i. e. attaching them together):

```
$ cat hello.html hello1.html hello2.html | mail -s "Subject Goes Here" myself@mailhost.example.com
```

Comment: Thanks, but will that really work, will cat command not take only 1 filename as a file and others as an argument?,  I need a space between each file merge so that the final content shall have three different line with a space between the , i will be more than happy to check your way out as well.

Comment: This will do the same as original in question, it will not add the blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, I have added code to add the blank lines.
`echo` will output a newline, it can also be used to output more.

```
>Final.html
cat hello.html >> Final.html
echo >> Final.html
cat hello1.html >> Final.html
echo >> Final.html
cat hello2.html >> Final.html
```

This next one uses a bracket, to reduce the amount of code.

```
{
     cat hello.html
     echo
     cat hello1.html
     echo
     cat hello2.html 
}> Final.html
```

Comment: Since i am writing in Linux text while, I shall be using echo as well right before all the lines you have mentioned?

Comment: Both of my examples (above), should produce exactly the same output. However the 2nd has repeated code, so is nicer. (it only has `> Final.html` once)

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `awk` (which supports the `ENDFILE` special pattern):

```
awk '1; ENDFILE { print "" }' hello.html hello1.html hello2.html >Final.html
```

The `awk` script passes the data unmodified data of each file in turn (the `1;` may be replaced by `{ print }`, which does the same thing).  At the end of each file, the `ENDFILE` block will output an empty line.

To additionally insert the name of the file before the data of each file (this was not part of the question):

```
awk 'BEGINFILE { print FILENAME } 1
     ENDFILE   { print "" }' hello.html hello1.html hello2.html >Final.html
```

The special pattern `BEGINFILE` works just like `ENDFILE` but will be triggered before reading the first line of a new file.  The `FILENAME` variable is a standard `awk` variable and contains the pathname of the current input file.